# UBSAN vptr error (member call on address ... which does point to object of type ...) on GCC but not Clang

Tags: c++, gcc

Running our unit tests compiled with UBSAN enabled on GCC 9.2.0 gave an error. The tests themselves are based on the rather dated CppUnit framework which uses a lot of inheritance.
I managed to reduce the problem down to this (unfortunately still rather long) reproducible example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//------------------------------------------------------
// 1. Minimal re-implementation of CppUnit API
//------------------------------------------------------
class Test
{
public:
    virtual ~Test() {};

    virtual void run() = 0;

    virtual std::string getName() const = 0;
};


class TestFixture
{
public:
    virtual ~TestFixture() {};

    virtual void setUp() {}; // Default implementation does nothing

    virtual void tearDown() {}; // Default implementation does nothing
};

class TestCase : public Test, public TestFixture
{
public:
    TestCase(const std::string& name): name_(name) {}

    std::string getName() const override { return name_; }

    virtual void runTest() = 0;

    //void setUp() override {}; // Implement these and there are no errors

    //void tearDown() override {}; // Implement these and there are no errors
private:
    std::string name_;
};

//------------------------------------------------------
// 2. Our own custom test class
//------------------------------------------------------
class CustomTestCaseMethodFunctor
{
public:
    using Method = void (TestCase::*)();

    CustomTestCaseMethodFunctor(
        TestCase *target,
        Method method)
    : target_(target)
    , method_(method)
    {
    }

    bool operator()() const
    {
        // The following line reports an UBSAN error when called
        // with target_ being a CustomTestCase instance and method_
        // being TestCase::setUp
        (target_->*method_)();
        return true;
    }

private:
    TestCase *target_;
    Method method_;
};

class CustomTestCase : public TestCase
{
public:
    CustomTestCase(const std::string& name, const std::string& msg): TestCase(name), m_msg(msg)
    {

    }

    // Overrides TestCase::runTest()
    void runTest() override
    {
        std::cout << getName() << " msg: " << m_msg << "\n";
    }

    // Overrides TestFixture::setUp()
    void setUp() override
    {
        std::cout << getName() << " setUp()\n";
    }

    // Overrides TestFixture::tearDown()
    void tearDown() override
    {
        std::cout << getName() << " tearDown()\n";
    }

    // Overrides Test::run()
    void run() override
    {
        // The reason we don't just call the methods directly is that in the
        // real CppUnit framwork these functor objects are passed to a special
        // protect function that catches exceptions and reports an error etc.
        CustomTestCaseMethodFunctor set_up_functor(this, &TestCase::setUp);
        CustomTestCaseMethodFunctor run_functor(this, &TestCase::runTest);
        CustomTestCaseMethodFunctor tear_down_functor(this, &TestCase::tearDown);

        set_up_functor();
        run_functor();
        tear_down_functor();
    }
private:
    std::string m_msg;
};

//------------------------------------------------------
// 3. Set up tests and run
//------------------------------------------------------
int main(int, char**)
{
    CustomTestCase test_caller("CustomTestCase", "some stuff");
    std::cout << "address of 'test_caller': " << &test_caller << "\n";
    test_caller.run();
}
```

Compiling with `g++ -O0 -g -fsanitize=undefined example.cpp -o example` and running gives the following error message:

```
address of 'test_caller': 0x7ffdfa00f050
main.cpp:62:28: runtime error: member call on address 0x7ffdfa00f058 which does not point to an object of type 'TestCase'
0x7ffdfa00f050: note: object is base class subobject at offset 8 within object of type 'CustomTestCase'
 01 00 00 00  88 31 40 00 00 00 00 00  d0 31 40 00 00 00 00 00  70 f0 00 fa fd 7f 00 00  0e 00 00 00
              ^                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                       vptr for 'TestFixture' base class of 'CustomTestCase'
CustomTestCase setUp()
CustomTestCase msg: some stuff
CustomTestCase tearDown()
```

The code runs fine and does what it is supposed to do, but the error message is a bit worrying.

The problem seems to stem from the fact that `TestCase` inherits from both `Test` and `TestFixture` and UBSAN thinks the object at the pointer is not a `TestFixture` object. I was thinking it could be due how vtables for classes with multiple inheritance is implemented in GCC compared to Clang/LLVM which is what UBSAN was made for. Guided by this idea I tried compiling with clang: `clang++ -O0 -g -fsanitize=undefined example.cpp -o example_clang` and when I run that I get no UBSAN errors.

You can see the results for yourself on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/WW6jbPrqM

So are we relying on undefined behavior? Or is this a bug in GCC's UBSAN implementation?

I already have a solution to the problem (replace the object and method pointer in `CustomTestCaseMethodFunctor` with `std::function` or a lambda), but I would like to understand this issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a comment on line 62 in the source, so we can see what line you're getting errors about.

Comment: When you're setting up the functors, e.g. `set_up_functor` should you be using `static_cast<TestCase*>(this)`?  Implicit casts can be troublesome when using multiple inheritance, given there are multiple vtables.  You'll often find a static cast yields a different pointer value compared to "this"

Comment: @Den-Jason your suggestion doesn't change anything. How can an implicit cast be different than a static cast?

Comment: I *think* (with an emphasis on "think") that gcc's sanitizer is being overly aggressive.

Comment: @Den-Jason An implicit conversion to a base class does the same as `static_cast` to that base. Also, `TestCase` is the only immediate base of `CustomTestCase`, so there should be no room for confusion. (What you need to look out for with multiple inheritance is implicit conversions to `void*`, `reinterpret_cast`, and C-style casts.)